# Car rentals cross-border between USA & Canada

Tags: usa, canada, automobiles, rental

Looking to hire or lease a car  for 6 weeks in New Brunswick, Canada  and return it to New York.(Oct- Nov 2015) Any suggestions how to go about this as all inquiries so far say "no car available"

Answer (score 3):

This is likely dependent on the company, as some won't necessarily allow one-way cross-border rentals, or may not have a license to cross the borders for their commercial operation.

I'm assuming, however, that you've tried some large ones.  It's also possible that they're full then - are you trying a busy period? New Brunswick doesn't have that big a population, it's possible they aren't particularly set up for rentals like that.

Do you absolutely need a car? There are buses, planes and trains.  Even a cheap bus from Toronto to Buffalo, for example, and you could rent a car from NB to Toronto, and then from Buffalo for your USA segment.

It's [noted on tripadvisor](http://www.tripadvisor.com.au/ShowTopic-g155033-i134-k4923184-One_way_car_rental_across_US_Canada_border-Quebec_City_Quebec.html) that one-way rentals across borders are often the most expensive type, so that may even save you money.  They suggest looking on a multi-vendor search site like expedia as well, you may have more luck. I use kayak.com, but up to you.

Comment: Thankyou for taking the time to respond. We do need a car so two different rentals will probably be the best option for us.

Answer (score 3):

The drop fee for a one way cross border rental will be quite high, as the car would have to be repositioned since having a matching reverse rental would be highly unlikely.

You are better off doing a Canadian rental, then transport (bus, plane) to New York, then a USA rental.

The other option is buying a second hand car, driving it for a while, then selling it off.  But not sure what the title transfer procedure would be when you sell it in New York state (perhaps some duty or import fees?)

Answer (score 2):

Another solution would be to rent two cars, using public transit between. A one-way car rental from Bangor, Maine to NYC is about $50-60/day, although whether rates that far in advance are meaningful, I don't know.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance. I'll look into your suggestion